# the_excerpt() is not trimming at <!--more-->

Tags: excerpt, read-more

I am using the following code:

```
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

This trims after 50 ish words, way after the `<!--more-->` I added in the post's source.

This, instead, correctly trims out the part before `<!--more-->` as expected.

```
    <?php the_content("", TRUE); ?>
```

How do I change `the_excerpt()` so that it returns the part before `<!--more-->`?

I tried using `get_extended()` but it does not produce the same output as `the_excerpt()`; specifically, it does not add `<p>` tags, and probably something else.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`the_excerpt()` does not recognise or support the `<!-- more -->` tag. From [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/):

> The `<!--more-->` quicktag requires templates to use [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) whereas using excerpts requires, and allows, template writers to explicitly choose whether to display full posts (using [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)) or excerpts (using [`the_excerpt()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/)).

The point is that `the_excerpt()` allows theme authors (you) to *require* an excerpt. This is automatically created by trimming the content, but if the user needs a specific excerpt then they can enter a manual excerpt. Either way they cannot accidentally display the full post content.

On the other hand `the_content()` lets the *user* decide whether or not to use an excerpt. If they do want one, then they use the `<!-- more -->` tag. If they don't, then they leave it out and the full post will be displayed.

As a theme author you need to decide which you should support. If displaying the full content of the post would break your layout, then you should use `the_excerpt()`, but if the theme would look fine either way, then use `the_content()`.

If you want the user to decide between these options then you could create a Customiser setting that let's the user choose. Then in your templates you could check this value and use the appropriate tag:

```
<?php
if ( 'excerpt' === get_theme_mod( 'setting_name_here' ) ) {
    the_excerpt();
} else {
    the_content( '', true );
}
?>
```

Comment: I just noticed the_excerpt works as expected in the homepage, it's only in the single page that ignores <!-- more--> and just spits out 50 words. What gives? thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well if you read my answer, that’s the expected behaviour. Why are you using the_excerpt on the single template?

Comment: oh well, i just want to add a different markup around it, but i can't get the_excerpt to work in the single page like it works in the home